# Change paths text in url in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have made a test multilanguage app where I translate all the texts into different languages using ngx-translate and adding the translations in .json files. The problem is that I don't know how to make it so that the urls with the name of the components and the title, description... meta tags are also translated.

Does anyone know how it could be done?

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Please upload necessary code with your post

Comment: I created [this package](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-seo/src/lib/directives) which can be used [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/blob/master/apps/seo-demo/src/app/pages/home/home.component.html#L2).